# Call one velocity content to another velocity template

Tags: velocity

Can we call one velocity template to another template to reuse the code?
For example i have one velocity template where common code is there and that common code i want to use in another velocity template.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

That's precisely the purpose of the #parse directive.

Please check the [Velocity Users Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#Parse).